# Error occurred in my android studio Project.....can't find the solution on google

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made a simple app. It was running fine. I had never used git. So, I watched a simple tutorial on youtube and installed the git and have made an account on Github. And also have added the account on the android studio and made the initial commit. Just after that, an error is showing in (ExampleInstrumentedTest.java)... and when I try to run the app. it builds without error but fails to install in my android device.

I searched for the solution on google. And find that disabling the instant run can solve this. but in the latest version of the android studio. instant run feature is not used.[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcIAs.png) and [here is the screenshot for dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4bJI.png)

Edit: now I have found out that it is running on other android devices but not on my android device. I think this problem arose after I unrooted my android device.

Comment: please add your dependencies

Comment: I have added, have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Just close the project and import it same.Its work for me.
**File > New > Import Project > your project**

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build >Clean Project followed by Rebuild  Project.
If it works then ok, otherwise uncommit git changes and then rebuild Project. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

It was not installing the app on my device since I had unrooted my phone. So, I rooted the phone again and now the problem is solved.